# Is it possible to search elements using regular expressions in locators using Tcl Selenium Webdriver interface?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, tcl, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to search elements usign regular expressions in locators.

The following works

```
set login [$window element by_class_name "frost-button"]
```

But the following doesn't work.

```
set login [$window element by_class_name "*button"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. When you call something like "by_class_name", the program will try to find element(s) that match the class name exactly that you pass as paramether.

So, if you try to search a class that contains a string, you need to use xpath or cssselector, but without using regex as well.

in Cssselector, the selector is this way:

```
*[class*='button']
```

Also, in Xpath is this way:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'button')]
```

i think to convert it into a tcl string you need to insert some slashes in the string. As i don't know the tcl, better I don't try.

Comment: Either `//*\[contains(@class,\ 'button')]` or `{//*[contains(@class, 'button')]}` lets this string get past the Tcl command evaluator.